# What platforms are available to create AR Map Directions similar to Live View Walking Directions in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, augmented-reality

I had an idea to hide gifts for different occasions (Christmas, Birthday, Anniversary, etc) around the house, and create an app that will act as a "locator". Preferably, I would like to have AR directions similar to those shown in Google Maps' Live View Walking Directions. Are there any platforms that exist to help me map out my house and create these AR Markers showing which way to go?

My worst case scenario at the moment is to just place an AirTag with the gift and let them use my phone to find the item. This will require almost no prep time, but loses the "cool" factor. I don't mind spending a lot of time on this as it's something I would enjoy doing.

Answer (score 0):

After some extended research, I was able to find that Google's ARCore Cloud Anchors are exactly what I am looking for. More information can be found here: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/cloud-anchors

Cloud Anchors let you map a location, place anchors, and attach virtual content to these anchors. These are great for private locations and events where you can show up ahead of time, map the location, and place content.